# Angular js script loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this is way i run my angular aaplication

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js"  ng-app="BasicHttpAuthExample"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <script src="<?= ASSETS_PATH ?>/js/app2.js"></script>
        <script src="<?= ASSETS_PATH ?>/js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="http://localhost/SPA_DEMO/assets/js/jquery.countTo.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="BasicHttpAuthExample"> 
        <nav id="fh5co-main-nav" role="navigation">  
            <a href="#" class="js-fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle active" id="Close"><i></i></a>
            <div class="js-fullheight fh5co-table">
                <div class="fh5co-table-cell js-fullheight">
                    <ul>
                        <li></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    <ng-view>
    </ng-view>
</body>
</html>
```

In this when i am loading view script loaded in this file are not available in view. how to load some script every time view is loading or how to make available loaded script in view also.

Comment: remove attribute `ng-app="BasicHttpAuthExample"` from html tag.

Comment: Why do you have two ng-app="BasicHttpAuthExample", where is your ng-controller(s) directive and what do you mean under "view script"? Also would be nice to see the content of your js files. Instead of adding the content here, a better way would be to create a plunker and provide a link to it. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

try to make sure you load scripts at  the bottom near close of `body` tag so that they load when the dom has loaded. Also make sure external scripts like Jquery and other libraries are loaded first because your javascript files may depend on them.

You dont have to specify ng-app directive twice. its okay on the body tag.
you are missing a controller directive as well.

```
 <html class="no-js" > <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>

    </head>
    <body ng-app="BasicHttpAuthExample" ng-controller="//your controller"> 
        <nav id="fh5co-main-nav" role="navigation" >  
            <a href="#" class="js-fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle active" id="Close"><i></i></a>
            <div class="js-fullheight fh5co-table">
                <div class="fh5co-table-cell js-fullheight">
                    <ul>
                        <li></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

    <ng-view>
    </ng-view>
        <script src="http://localhost/SPA_DEMO/assets/js/jquery.countTo.js"></script>
        <script src="<?= ASSETS_PATH ?>/js/app2.js"></script>
        <script src="<?= ASSETS_PATH ?>/js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```